# php динамическое создание кнопки и логики для нее

Tags: php, mysql

Есть запрос SELECT и циклом все выводится на страницу.

```
<?php while ($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()){  // цикл полученных строк?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row["id"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["link"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["tg_name"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["amount"]; ?></td>
        <?php $name_isset = $row["order_id"];?>
        <td><form method="POST"><input type="submit" value="Удалить" name ="<?php echo $name_isset; ?>">
        <?php
         if(isset($_POST['<?php echo $name_isset; ?>']))
         {
         $connect->query("DELETE FROM `payments` WHERE order_id = '<?php echo $name_isset; ?>'");
         }
        ?>
        </form></td>
    </tr>
```

Cоответственно, вот это `$_POST['<?php echo $name_isset; ?>']`и вот это `$connect->query("DELETE FROM`payments`WHERE order_id = '<?php echo $name_isset; ?>'");` не работает, как сделать, чтобы динамически создавались кнопки с такой логикой, каждая кнопка имеет название того что надо вставать в sql запрос и  удалить???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php         if(isset($_POST['<?php echo $name_isset; ?>
```

Вы пытаетесь использовать код PHP внутри кода PHP. Так не получится.

```
$connect->query("DELETE FROMpaymentsWHERE order_id = '<?php echo $name_isset; ?>'");
```

Нужно записать

```
$connect->query("DELETE FROM payments WHERE order_id = " . $name_isset);
```